# Simplified way to use NOT IN statements for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

how can I simplify this query? unfortunately this is not working

```
$Query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM order_number where trans_id NOT IN (SELECT order_no from billing)
                                       AND NOT IN(SELECT order_no from pending)
                                       AND NOT IN(SELECT order_no from on_process)
                                       AND NOT IN(SELECT order_no from finished)");
```

is there any other way around this? im trying to print trans_id row if its not in billing, pending, on_process and finished.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why  billing, pending,  on_process and finished are not states in an order table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM order_number 
where trans_id NOT IN 
(
   SELECT order_no from billing
   union 
   SELECT order_no from pending
   union 
   SELECT order_no from on_process
   union
   SELECT order_no from finished
)
```

or as you tried it

```
SELECT * FROM order_number 
where trans_id NOT IN (SELECT order_no from billing)
  AND trans_id NOT IN (SELECT order_no from pending)
  AND trans_id NOT IN (SELECT order_no from on_process)
  AND trans_id NOT IN (SELECT order_no from finished)
```

Comment: @phenomenon09 remember to accept or post your own solution as answer,

Comment: I'd suggest NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN, because that's probably what OP wants. (NULL's in sub-selects...)

Comment: If you care an iota about performance, don't use the version with `union` in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to "simplify" the query.  With proper indexes on the tables in the four subqueries, it should be quite efficient.  If `orderno` could be `NULL` in any of the tables, then I would recommend using `not exists` instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM order_number  o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select order_no from billing where b.order_no = o.trans_id) AND
      NOT EXISTS (select order_no from pending p where p.order_no = o.trans_id) AND
      NOT EXISTS (select order_no from on_process op where op.order_no = o.trans_id) AND
      NOT EXISTS (select order_no from finished f where f.order_no = o.trans_id);
```

The proper indexes are:  `billing(order_no)`, `pending(order_no)`, `finished(order_no)`, and `on_process(order_no)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make left joins on the tables, and filter out the records where there is no matching records:

```
select
  n.*
from
  order_number n
  left join billing b on b.order_no = n.trans_id
  left join pending p on p.order_no = n.trans_id
  left join on_process o on o.order_no = n.trans_id
  left join finished f on f.order_no = n.trans_id
where
  b.order_no is null and
  p.order_no is null and
  o.order_no is null and
  f.order_no is null
```